# Spring Boot @Async not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, asynchronous

I expect that `uploadImage` method finishes once the file is uploaded to AWS, while `scanFile` method is still running asynchronously in the background;

```
@RestController
public class EmailController {
    @PostMapping("/upload")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void uploadImage(@RequestParam MultipartFile photos) {
        awsAPIService.uploadImage(photos);
    }
}

...
@Service
public class AwsAPIService {
    public void uploadImage(MultipartFile file) {
        try {
            File fileToUpload = this.convertMultiPartToFile(file);
            String fileName = this.generateFileName(file);
            s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(AWS_S3_QUARANTINE_BUCKET_NAME,fileName, fileToUpload));
            fileToUpload.delete();
            // start scan file
            scanFile();
        } ...
    }

    @Async
    public void scanFile() {
        log.info("Start scanning");
        String queueUrl = sqs.getQueueUrl("bucket-antivirus").getQueueUrl();
        List<Message> messages = sqs.receiveMessage(new ReceiveMessageRequest().withQueueUrl(queueUrl)
                .withWaitTimeSeconds(20)).getMessages();
        for (Message message : messages) {
        // delete message
        ...
         }
     }
}


...
@EnableAsync
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
        taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(200);
        taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
        return taskExecutor;
    }
}
```

But this seems still running synchronously. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `@Async` and other Spring method-level annotations like `@Transactional` work only on the external, bean-to-bean method call. An internal method call from `uploadImage()` to `scanFile()` in the same bean won't trigger the proxy implementing the Spring behaviour. As per Spring docs:

> In proxy mode (which is the default), only external method calls coming in through the proxy are intercepted. This means that self-invocation, in effect, a method within the target object calling another method of the target object, will not lead to an actual transaction at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with @Transactional. Also, the proxy must be fully initialized to provide the expected behaviour so you should not rely on this feature in your initialization code, i.e. @PostConstruct.

You could configure AspectJ to enable annotations on internal method calls, but it's usually easier to refactor the code.

Comment: Thanks, May I ask how should I refactor my code to make it as an external call for `scanFile` method?

Comment: @Cosaic one way to do it is to call `awsAPIService.scanFile()` from the `@Controller`, just after `awsAPIService.uploadImage(photos)`.

Comment: Why isn't it considered as internal call anymore by moving it from service class to controller class?

Comment: @Cosaic internal calls are done between methods in the same bean, anything between two different beans is external.

Comment: If I add another method call in the async method, does that method become async? Should I still add `@async` for that method?

Comment: @Cosaic not sure tbh, I never had a use case to nest `@Async` methods.